# Laravel route to controller not working

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes, controllers

I'm trying to add a new controller to an existing laravel project. The application already has some pages at `/users` and I am trying to add a RESTful API which works separately to this. I would like the API to be available at `api/users`.

I have created the controller using PHP artisan:

```
php artisan controller:make ApiUsersController
```

I have added the following to my routes:

```
Route::controller('api/users', 'ApiUsersController');
```

However when I hit the URL I just receive the site's 'Page could not be found' message.

Is there something I have missed?

Comment: check :- Route::get('api/users', 'ApiUsersController');

Comment: `Route::get('api/users', 'ApiUsersController@index');` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue you're having is that you've used `Route::controller` rather than `Route::resource`.

`Route::resource` maps routes to the seven RESTful methods that the controller generator creates by default. `Route::controller` maps them to methods that you add yourself that have the HTTP method as part of their name, in your case if you had a method called `getIndex` it would be called on a GET request to `/api/users/index` or if you had one called `postStore` it would be called on a POST request to `/api/users/store`.

In order to add the API prefix to the route you could use the following:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    Route::resource('users', 'ControllerName');
});
```

You could also add any other controllers in the API within the same callback.

Comment: I'm aware there is a `Route::resource()` method. How would I prepend the `api/` to it though, as the examples I see seem to just use the model name and controller name as parameters.

Comment: Ah sorry, I totally missed that. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Route::controller does this method require a specific PHP version? I can run this successfully in php 7.1 and below but not working on php 7.3.